# pass data from wordpress theme to wordpress plugin via hook

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made a custom wordpress theme with a custom hook.
This needs to integrate with a function in a custom plugin.

I need to be able to send a value to the function which it runs.

I have tried using this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

but that does not work.

How can I send data from the front page to the function in my plugin.

this is my current code

template code

print (apply_filters('CI_printsingle',$returnvalue));

plug-in code

function select_single{

```
return "hello world";
```

}

add_filter('CI_printsingle','select_single');

Comment: `apply_filters()` accepts a 3rd parameter for arguments which you can pass. See here [CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters)